# No se imprimen los caracteres chinos al conectarse a sql desde java

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo una función que lo único que hace es imprimir todos los valores de un campo de una tabla, sin embargo tengo letras chinas guardadas en la base de datos, y desde sql server se ven bien, pero al imprimirlas en java muestra solo signos de interrogación, está es mi función :

```
public void imprimir() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;databaseName=foo;characterEncoding=UTF‑8",
                "usuario", "password");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLA");

        while (resultSet.next())
            System.out.println(resultSet.getString("VALOR"));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Connect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Connect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: estás seguro que el string está almacenado correctamente en la base de datos?, qué tipo de dato estás usando?

Comment: Gracias, es eso, estaba usando varchar en lugar de nvarchar

Comment: ah, no hay problema

Comment: @Lamak, si quieres ponlo como respuesta

Comment: ok, agregué una respuesta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una posibilidad sea que no estás guardando el caracter como unicode en la base de datos. Para esto necesitas usar el tipo de datos `nvarchar` en vez de `varchar`.

Answer (score 1):

Debes especificar el encoding a UTF-8

Proba lo siguiente

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
out.println(resultSet.getString("VALOR"));
```

O establece en el ide el text file encoding en UTF-8